# Stream Target in wowza

Tags: php, curl, streaming, wowza, broadcasting

I have implemented for creating stream target through php with the help of curl.

```
<?php
$service_url = 'http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/liveSource';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
$curl_post_data ='
{
"restURI": "http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/testlive"
"stream_target": {
 "name": “defaultTarget”,
 "provider": "rtmp",
 "username": "liveSource",
 "password": "Welcomehere",
 "stream_name": “customTarget”,
 "primary_url": "http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/liveSource",
  } "https://api.cloud.wowza.com/api/v1/stream_targets"
}';
$headers = array(
  'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
 'Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8' 
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl); 
curl_close($curl);

echo $curl_response;
?>
```

But it is showing error as success as false with code 401

```
 {"message":"The request requires user authentication","success":false,"wowzaServer":"4.4.0","code":"401"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to create a stream target in Wowza Streaming engine, I would start with a simple example as follows:

```
<?php  
// Modify values here
$entryName = "ppSource";
$appName = "live";
$streamName = "myStream";
$userName = "user";
$password = "pass";
$profile = "rtmp";
$server = "localhost";
// End modification

$url = "http://{$server}:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/{$appName}/pushpublish/mapentries/{$entryName}";
$json = "{
   \"restURI\": \"http://{$server}:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/{$appName}/pushpublish/mapentries/{$entryName}\",
   \"serverName\":\"_defaultServer_\",
            \"sourceStreamName\": \"{$streamName}\",
            \"entryName\": \"{$entryName}\",
            \"profile\": \"{$profile}\",
            \"host\": \"{$server}\",
            \"application\":\"{$appName}\",
            \"userName\":\"{$userName}\",
            \"password\":\"{$password}\",
            \"streamName\":\"{$streamName}\"
}'";

$ch = curl_init($url);                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER      ,0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");                                                            
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);             
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                    'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'Content-Length: '.strlen($json)));
$contents = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$obj =  json_decode($contents);
var_dump($obj);
```

However if you are trying to initiate a live stream through our cloud api, here is a small example (only) of what your request might look like:

```
// Modify values here 
$cloudApiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$cloudApiAccessKey="xxxxxxxxxx";
// End modification 

$url = "https://api.cloud.wowza.com/api/v1/live_streams";
$json = "{
   \"live_stream\": {
     \"id\": \"1234abcd\",
     \"name\": \"MyLiveStream\",
     \"transcoder_type\": \"transcoded\",
     \"billing_mode\": \"pay_as_you_go\",
     \"broadcast_location\": \"us_west_california\",
     \"recording\": false,
     \"encoder\": \"wowza_gocoder\",
     \"delivery_method\": \"push\",
     \"use_stream_source\": false,
     \"aspect_ratio_width\": 1280,
     \"aspect_ratio_height\": 720,
     \"connection_code\": \"033334\",
     \"connection_code_expires_at\": \"2015-11-25T12:06:38.453-08:00\",
     \"source_connection_information\": {
       \"primary_server\": \"6022e9.entrypoint.cloud.wowza.com\",
       \"host_port\": 1935,
       \"application\": \"app-464b\",
       \"stream_name\": \"32a5814b\",
       \"disable_authentication\": false,
       \"username\": \"client2\",
       \"password\": \"1234abcd\"
     },
     \"player_responsive\": true,
     \"player_countdown\": false,
     \"player_embed_code\": \"in_progress\",
     \"player_hds_playback_url\": \"http://wowzadev-f.akamaihd.net/z/32a5814b_1@7217/manifest.f4m\",
     \"player_hls_playback_url\": \"http://wowzadev-f.akamaihd.net/i/32a5814b_1@7217/master.m3u8\",
     \"hosted_page\": true,
     \"hosted_page_title\": \"MyLiveStream\",
     \"hosted_page_url\": \"in_progress\",
     \"hosted_page_sharing_icons\": true
   } 
}";

$ch = curl_init($url);                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER      ,0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                    'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'wsc-api-key: '.$cloudApiKey,
                    'wsc-access-key: '.$cloudApiAccessKey,
 );
$contents = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

This is obtained from the [examples page](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?777-How-to-broadcast-a-live-stream-by-using-the-Wowza-Streaming-Cloud-REST-API#exampleStartStop) and modified to fit into a PHP related request.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: thanks for reply. I was able to create stream target from terminal by adding  --digest -u "user:pass" but how to pass this in above script. As above script(your answer) is also giving same response. I have authentication type as digest in server.xml

Comment: I've modified the solution and you can see two lines commented out within the WSE example that demonstrate how you could leverage digest authentication.

Comment: thanks for the reply matt. This solution worked for us thanks a lot. Can you help me a little more "How to delete all the targets that have been created so far with curl script. "

Comment: To remove via Rest API you will need the custom request verb of DELETE.  To do this, comment out the POST options and include curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE"). Then you simply need to point the request to the proper end point as shown [here](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?745-Stream-targets-query-examples-(push-publishing)#deletepp)